# External interface to add field/dropdown values to tuleap

Tags: tuleap

We are using the Tuleap 7.0 for Project management. We have a new requirement that we need to provide access permission to specific users other than administrator role to create field's value with dependencies. For eg: We are having a field called category. Categories are SUV, Sedan, etc., Now we want to add a new category name called Wagon. But I do not want the administrator to add this each and every time instead I need to give permission to either project manager or to some other user roles to add the same. Also we have to add subcategories to corresponding categories. So either we need to provide access permission to specific user or a external interface other than tuleap to add the category and subcategory with field dependencies.

If we have to create an external interface, we do not know in which table the data and dependencies will be available. So kindly let us know is it possible to provide access permission to specific users for creating field's values and dependencies or else let us know detail on table structure that where the insertion of field values happen and the dependencies between fields will be available. Table schema will be more easier. Please help

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a group to be Trackers administrators but not fully Project administrators, maybe it answers your need but not sure. If you want to go this way, you have to choice: either you set it in the Trackers > administration > manage permissions for each project or in the global administration of the platform in admin > permissions delegation.

If you only want people to only be able to add values to this particular field, I don't think it is really possible. What you can do is to put an openlist instead of a simple list or even modify your trackers structure to have a tracker that represents all the category and set category by doing an artifact link. So to add a category simply submit a new artifact in the category tracker.

For the table schema I'm sorry but I don't have such document.